# Finding Geometric Volumes

Tags: calculus, volume

Find the volume of the solids below whose cross-sections perpendicular to the x-axis are (The images are in the link below)

http://people.whitman.edu/~hundledr/courses/M126F13/M126/Group02.pdf

PLease Help! Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to ME. You will find helpful answers if you show some effort. What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: well i know how to compute the integral when i get it, i just dont know how to set it up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

For the first one it is $0\le x\le 4,$ $-x/4\le y,z\le x/4.$ Thus, the volume is obtained by computing

$$\int_0^4 \int_{-x/4}^{x/4}\int_{-x/4}^{x/4}dzdydx.$$ Compare this with the volume of the pyramide of basis a square of edge $2$ and height $4.$